# Restricting access to a website by domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service, domain-name

I'm privately testing an Azure web app that talks to other APIs. I'm only letting certain IP addresses get through, like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <ipSecurity>
        <add allowed="true" ipAddress="192.168.100.1" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
     </ipSecurity>
  </security>
```

However, one API doesn't have a reliable static IP address. So I'm trying to let it through by domain, like this:

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <ipSecurity>
        <add allowed="true" domainName="example.com." />
     </ipSecurity>
  </security>
```

The docs say: "Specifies domain name on which to impose a restriction rule. You can use an asterisk (*) as a wildcard."

I think I have the wrong domain name (just guessing at this point, need to look at logs) because it's not working. I've tried "*.example.com", "example.com", and "example.com." (dot on the end).

Which leads me to ask:

1) What format does this domainName string have to be in? I can't find any examples. For example, does it need the protocol, "https" or "http"?

2) How do I see the domain names/IP addresses trying to connect to an Azure web app? In other words, how do I see the equivalent of fiddler traffic? I need to verify the endpoint of the API that is talking to my site.

Answer (score 0):

1) Based on log analysis, which gave me the IP addresses, which I then converted to domain names using an online tool, the domains I needed to let through were of the form:

subsubdomain.subdomain.example.com.

Because of load balancing, I couldn't just let through one domain. I was forced to use this string, which worked:

*.subdomain.example.com

2) I found the relevant IP addresses which I then converted to domains (using an online tool) by using the Kudu web interface. First I clicked "Debug console", which showed the file structure, then "LogFiles", then "http", then "RawLogs". I downloaded the logs and looked through them in Excel.